# CodeBlocks Keeps Crashing

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks

My code blocks keeps popping up this grey box:

[image: this grey box]

whenever I type `char`, `printf` or any variable that I'm using. I'm guessing it's the suggests bar that's not loading properly. Anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried restarting the app and it's not working.

Comment: Note that this is about the tool usage, so the actual code doesn't seem to be the culprit. You might need to put more information about your runtime into the question.

Comment: You will probably get better support if you try on the code::blocks forums. https://forums.codeblocks.org

Comment: Try reinstalling it

Comment: What’s with the last line of code?  Looks to be erroneously pasted there?